Time Weighted Vega of Options
What is the correct way to calculate Time weighted vega for options?
From searching in Google, saw this reference: http://www.topquants.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Van-Gulik-Risk-management-at-Optiver.pdf

I also saw from a Risk System, the calculation of time-weighted vega as:
Vega_weighted = (((1-exp(3t))/3)* Vega
On the above two ways, I have few questions:

Which of the above method is more accurate?
Why not just divide the Vega by sqrt(T) to annualise the vega?
Why is there a factor of 3 in both equations?

